# Call mvc url.action from angular controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have this tabset:

```
<tabset justified="true" class="tabsetnowrap">
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabshomepage track by $index" heading="{{tab.title}}" ng-click="homePageNavigate(tab.type)" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
</tab>
```

It is created in a angular controller:

```
    $scope.tabshomepage = [];
    $scope.tabshomepage.push(
    { title: 'Hjem', type: 'HOM', order: 1, active: true, disabled: false, color: 'black' },
    { title: 'Dirty', type: 'DIR', order: 2, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'purple' },
    { title: 'Dating', type: 'DAT', order: 3, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'green' },
    { title: 'Bloggers', type: 'SOC', order: 4, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'lblue' },
    { title: 'Konto', type: 'ACO', order: 5, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'black' },
    { title: 'Om os', type: 'ABU', order: 6, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'black' },
    { title: 'Kontakt og FAQ', type: 'COF', order: 7, active: false, disabled: false, color: 'black' }
);
```

When a click is done on a tab, then the homePageNavigate function is performed.

```
$scope.homePageNavigate = function (type) {
    if(type == 'DIR'){
        //Perform a @Url.Action("Index", "Dirty", null)"
    }
    etc...
};
```

In that functin I want to call a mvc method: @Url.Action("Index", "Dirty", null)", and return a view("index")

What is best way to solve this problem?
Any workarounds? Or a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done something similar before by performing a bit of configuration in angular, through razor, on page load:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        angular.module('App').value('paths', {
            home: '@Url.Action("Index", "Dirty", null)'
            // more paths here
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Then you can inject and use `paths` anywhere within your angular app.
eg. Inside a controller called 'myCtrl`

```
angular.module('App').controller('myCtrl', ['paths', function(paths) {
    // you can use paths.home here
}]);
```

Comment: In my case I need this in the controller. Is it possible to tweak your code to be used in the controller?

Comment: Sure, it's just standard angular injection.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. I just relate to instance like "paths.home" and nothing else?

Comment: I hits the mvc controller, but it dosent return the view. Any solutions to part? If I do this from the cshtml page it works fine: <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Dirty", null)"><span class="medium-menu-box br-purple"><b>DIRTY</b></span></a>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The value of `paths.home` should hold the URL you need to navigate to. If you add a call to `console.log(paths.home)` within your controller, do you get the correct result printed in the console? If yes, then you need to write some code to navigate to that URL from within a controller. e.g. you can inject and use the $window service of angular like so: `$window.location(paths.home)`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to invoke ASP.Net MVC Controller action method using AngularJS as follows

In Javascript I wrote

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

angular.module('MyApp', [])

.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope,
$http) {

$scope.search = function () {

$http({

method: "GET",

url: "/home/GetData"

}).then(function mySuccess(response) {

$scope.name = response.data;

}, function myError(response) {

$scope.name = response.statusText;

});

}

}]);
In HTML part, I wrote

```
<button ng-click="search()">Get Data</button>
```

In Controller Action, I wrote return Json("You caught AngularJS", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);